# When to use attribute rel="canonical", rel="alternate", and hreflang for the link tag

Tags: seo, canonical-url, rel-canonical, hreflang, rel-alternate

I have this pages:

```
https://domain.tld/fr/post/mon-premier-article
https://domain.tld/fr/post/my-first-post
https://domain.tld/fr/post/mi-primera-publicacion
```

Same for site in English...

```
https://domain.tld/en/post/mon-premier-article
https://domain.tld/en/post/my-first-post
https://domain.tld/en/post/mi-primera-publicacion
```

... and in Spanish:

```
https://domain.tld/es/post/mon-premier-article
https://domain.tld/es/post/my-first-post
https://domain.tld/es/post/mi-primera-publicacion
```

With a `301` redirect from `https://domain.tld/post/mon-premier-article` to `https://domain.tld/fr/post/mon-premier-article`, depending on the user language (with fallback to `en`).

Only the blog post content change. Headers, footer, navigation... will be localized according to the user language.

So... here my `<link>` tags for the page `/post/mon-premier-article`:

```html
<link hreflang="fr" rel="canonical" href="https://domain.tld/post/mon-premier-article">
<link hreflang="en" rel="alternate" href="https://domain.tld/post/my-first-post">
<link hreflang="es" rel="alternate" href="https://domain.tld/post/mi-premera-publicacion">
```

---

Not sure if I use it right. Must I include the `/fr` in the URL?

The three pages have a different content, they're just translations. So no duplicate content here, right? So Maybe the following is better?

```html
<link hreflang="fr" rel="canonical" href="https://domain.tld/post/fr/mon-premier-article">
<link hreflang="en" rel="alternate" href="https://domain.tld/post/en/mon-premier-article">
<link hreflang="es" rel="alternate" href="https://domain.tld/post/es/mon-premier-article">
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a real-world example. In this case, EN (https://www.example.com) is the default language, and the other languages are alternates.

```html
<link href="https://www.example.com" rel="home">
<link href="https://www.example.com/contact-us" rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default">
<link href="https://www.example.com/fr/contactez-nous" rel="alternate" hreflang="fr-fr">
<link href="https://www.example.com/de/kontakt-aufnehmen" rel="alternate" hreflang="de-de">
<link href="https://www.example.com/contact-us" rel="alternate" hreflang="en-us">
```